# Import external config value into main config in grails

Tags: grails, configuration

I have an external config file **${userHome}/.grails/${appName}/config.groovy**:

```
package configs

grails.conf.logDirectory = '/home/serek/tmp/mamlog'
```

which I would like to import into **main grails Config.groovy**

```
grails.config.locations = ["file:${userHome}/.grails/${appName}/config.groovy"]
print grails.conf.logDirectory
log4j = {

    appenders {
        rollingFile name: 'infoLog', file: "${grails.conf.logDirectory}/info.log", threshold: org.apache.log4j.Level.INFO, maxFileSize: "1024MB", append: true
        rollingFile name: 'warnLog', file: 'warn.log', threshold: org.apache.log4j.Level.WARN, maxFileSize: "1024MB", append: true
        console name: 'stdout', layout: pattern(conversionPattern: '%d{yyyyMMdd.HHmmss.SSS} %r [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n')
    }
```

Unfortunately, **print grails.conf.logDirectory** is **not** visible in main config.

How can I handle that? Print outputs only [:]

```
Groovy: 2.1.9  
Grails: 2.3.2
```

========================================
I found solution, ex Config.groovy:

```
import org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml

    Yaml yaml = new Yaml()
    def extConfFilePath = "${userHome}/.grails/${appName}/mam.yaml" //my external conf in yaml
    def extConfFileContent = new File(extConfFilePath).text
    def extConf = yaml.load(extConfFileContent)
    grails.ext = extConf


    rollingFile name: 'infoLog', file: extConf.logDirectory + "info.log", threshold: org.apache.log4j.Level.INFO, maxFileSize: "1024MB", append: true
```

Comment: That should work... have you checked the file permissions on that file? Try reading that file from bootstrap.groovy - it might uncover an issue with permissions, etc. Also try removing the "grails.conf." part in case there is something special about grails.* and importing configs.

Answer (score 1):

I believe its because the external config files are pulled in **after** Config.groovy is executed. Therefore, println at that location doesn't work. Try printing it from any gsp page with,

```
println "logDir = ${grailsApplication.config.grails.conf.logDirectory}"
```

Comment: you pointed me into right direction to find solution for my problem, thanks.